# How can I get a related field ID in Django?

Tags: python, django

```
room = Reserved.objects.get(room=id)  ??
```

I want to get the ID of that field exists in the one model. For example:

**models.py**

```
class Room(models.Model):
    number = models.OneToOneField(RoomNumber)

class Reserved(models.Model):
    room = models.OneToOneField(Room, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

How can I get the ID of a room that exists in the `Reserved` table?

Comment: This isn't clear. What is `id`? Do you have a Room object? If so why can't you just do `room.reserved`?

Comment: unresolved reference 'room' i can not do this. Need related field objects id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use "__" (double underscore) when retrieving data in model field or template of a related object in reverse relation.

```
room = Reserved.objects.get(room__id=id)
```

here **room__id** will return the id of *room* in **Reserved** model which is in *one-to-one relation* with **Room** model.

Comment: it's better to use `room_id` as it does not perform a join on the related table. You only need to use the double underscore syntax when you are not querying the column that your foreign key is referencing